# Apache with self signed certificate, www subdomain hanging when requesting from browser

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, certificate

I created a staging site with a self signed certificate using:

```
mkdir /etc/ssl/wildcard.yourdomain.com
cd /etc/ssl/wildcard.yourdomain.com/
openssl genrsa 2048 > host.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days 3650 -key host.key > host.cert

openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -text < host.cert > host.info
cat host.cert host.key > host.pem
chmod 400 host.key host.pem

sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart

<VirtualHost *:443>

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/wildcard.yourdomain.com/host.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/wildcard.yourdomain.com/host.key
```

(from http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/how-to-create-self-signed-wildcard-ssl-certificates-for-apache/)

The issue I"m having is that *.yourdomain.com is just hanging.

I set up

`ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com`

As well as

`ServerName yourdomain.com`

When I navigate to "yourdomain.com" it works as expected.

But when I type: https://www.yourdomain.com chromium says "Establishing a secure connection" in the bottom right hand corner,

I enabled mod_ssl debug level logging but nothing is being logged when I type in url with `www`.  My end goal is to redirect `www` to my root domain https://yourdomain.com.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using namecheap's free dynamic dns:

```
Hostname,  IPADDRESS URL,         RECORD TYPE, TTL

@          m.y.i.p                A Address    1800
www        https://yourdomain.com URL Redirect 1800

SUb Domain SEttings:
*          https://yourdomain.com URL Redirect 1800
```

For subdomain settings, I also tried `https://*.yourdomain.com`

THank you

Comment: What's your DNS configuration look like for the `www` name?  And can you show us the output of `apachectl -S`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL redirect configuration in your DNS provider's name servers won't work with SSL.

The implementation of that kind of redirect really means that the provider has an A record configured on that name that points to servers of theirs, which then send HTTP redirects.

Those servers sending the redirects don't have any way to have a valid SSL certificate for your domain, so they listen on HTTP only - HTTPS connections will always fail.

Your server will need to be serving the HTTPS connections directly for the `www` name (then sending a redirect itself if that's desired) - change your record for the `www` name to an `A` or `CNAME` pointing to your server (if a `CNAME`, then point it to `yourdomain.com.`).